# Excel requires dates to be typed in American format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, date-format

In order to type a literal date into an Excel cell, I currently have to do it in the American format (mm/dd/yyyy). This is unacceptable.

How can I have it such that Excel will correctly recognise dates in the standard dd/mm/yyyy format when typing directly into cells?

Note: I am not asking how to use the "cell format" features of Excel. That is easy enough. I want to be able to directly input international dd/mm/yyyy dates into cells and have them register correctly, regardless of formatting.

Comment: Check your regional and language settings.

Comment: make it an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle - while you're at it, the only "universally accepted standard" date format is [ISO-8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html), which is yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel follows the Region and Language settings of Windows.

In Windows 10 : Settings > Time & language > Region & language. 
You can either take the default values, or you can fine-tune further in `Additional date, time, and regional settings` (date, time, number settings etc.)

Comment: Does that mean that I can't work on 2 files with dates in different formats at the same time?

Comment: @FedericoNafria Sorry for the very late reply. To my knowledge, you cannot input 01/02 in two files, and expecting that in the first file it means Feb 1st and in the other file Jan 2nd. Please note that this is about **writing directly in cells**. You can have cells with date values (which Excel stores as integers), and display them differently according to how you **format** the cells in Excel.